# ASUS EAH4670 vs. ASUS EAH4670 V2 -- Whats the difference?

Tags: graphics-card

I've been offered to buy a used *ASUS EAH4670/DI/1GD3* graphics card.

I went price-scouting to see if the offer I was given was fair, and I found out that there's a similar card, labelled *ASUS EAH4670/DI/1GD3 **V2***.

Question is; What's the difference? What's with the **V2**? What does it mean? Is it just a BIOS upgrade that I can do myself? Updated driver-software which I can download myself? Or is the card actually a better version--faster, more reliable (physical changes to the print), etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked them up on this Hardware.info (Dutch version sorry!)

The difference seems to be the **cooler**. For the rest I can't really see a difference ANYWHERE. So if cooling isn't going to be an issue and/or you don't mind noise levels, take the one that's the cheapest/easiest to get.

**V1:**

[image]

**V2:**

[image]

[ASUS EAH4670/DI/1GD3](http://www.hardware.info/nl-NL/productdb/bGZkbJibmJjKZ8g/viewproduct/ASUS_EAH4670DI1GD3/) and [ASUS EAH4670/DI/1GD3/V2](http://www.hardware.info/nl-NL/productdb/bGlkapiWmJLKaMg/viewproduct/ASUS_EAH4670DI1GD3V2/)

Comment: Seems I've got the newer version, as far as the heatsink goes. Thanks Ivo :)